# Update data in 2 tables with inner join

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm looking for a way to update the data in 2 tables with an inner join, but it doesn't work for me.

What I want is to update the data of the dbo.UserInfo table and at the same time the **Coin field** of the dbo.UserInfovariable table.

UserInfo table

| **UserIndex** | **UserID** | **UserPassword** | **Nickname** |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | admin | 123456 | UserPHP |

UserInfoVariable table

| **UserIndex** | Experience | Coin |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 989981454 | §8000 |

I have tried with this sentence, it only works with "a", when I add b.Coin the sentence stops working

```php
$sql = "UPDATE a 
            SET a.UserID = '$data[1]', 
                a.UserPassword = '$data[2]', 
                a.NickName = '$data[3]' , 
                b.Coin ='$data[4]' 
        FROM UserInfo as a 
            INNER JOIN UserInfoVariable b ON a.UserIndex = b.UserIndex 
        where a.UserIndex = '$data[0]'";
```

Comment: **WARNING:** Your code is **dangerous**. It is wide open to SQL injection attacks. Always, *always, **always*** parametrise your code. [Why do we always prefer using parameters in SQL statements?](//stackoverflow.com/q/7505808)

Comment: Also aliases like `a` is for `Customer` and `b` is for `Account`, or `t1` is for `Purchase` and `t2` is for `Transaction` aren't helpful for you or others that want to read your code. Use meaningful and *consistent* aliases for your objects. I suggest a read of [Bad Habits to Kick : Using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3).

Comment: Finally, add that you're storing **plain text** passwords into the mix, and you have a huge data and security breach just waiting to happen. Salt and Hash your passwords. It's not the 1980's any more; such fundament and fatal flaws are well known, well published on how foolish they are, and how to write proper parametrised queries and store credentials well documented. Ignorance is not an excuse.

Comment: Might as well note, as well, that SQL Server 2008 has been completely unsupported for almost 3 years now; you've told us you're using it (good) but you also really need to get that upgrade path sorted.

Comment: As for the question, a DML statement cannot affect multiple tables. If you want to `UPDATE` 2 tables, you need 2 `UPDATE` statements.